# Why can you find running water lower than $0^\circ \text{C}$?

Tags: thermodynamics, water, phase-transition, phase-diagram, freezing

I was looking at the phase diagram for water:

[image]

It seems there is not much of a region on the diagram at which you can be in the liquid phase, for temperatures lower than $0^\circ \text{C}$. I am asking if the motion of the water has any effect on the temperature at which it changes phase. This is because I have heard of several stories where running water was found to be at very low temperatures ($-20^\circ \text{C}$). Is this fake or does a running lake have a lower freezing point?

Comment: What does, "at very low temperatures" mean? Are you certain that somebody was not reporting the temperature of the _air_ above the water, and not the actual temperature of the water itself? I personally have seen running water in a place where the air temperature was that cold, but I did not try to measure the temperature of the water itself. The water that I saw was running in a stream bed, and the temperature of the Earth can be much warmer than the temperature of the air on a cold winter day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is highly unlikely that the stories about water flowing at -20C are true- unless the water was not actually at -20C, but just the surroundings.

It is possible to hold water at temperatures a few degrees below 0C if the water is extremely pure, held in an extremely clean and smooth-walled container, and isolated from stirring or shock. This metastable state is called *supercooling* and relies on there being no seed nuclei present to trigger the phase change from liquid to solid.

Entire clouds of water vapor can become supercooled, but the perturbation caused by an airplane flying through the cloud is enough to trigger freezing- and the ice thus created is stuck to the airplane's wings and can cause it to crash by overloading it or by interfering with the movement of its control surfaces.

You can also supercool water by increasing its ambient pressure- as for instance in the case of a bottle of beer placed in a freezer. As long as the cap is on the bottle, the beer will not freeze, but as soon as the cap is removed, the pressure is released and the beer quickly freezes into a two-phase slush of ice crystals contained in an alcohol-enriched liquid phase.